# MxGraph - Angularjs 1 - Integration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mxgraph

I tried to add mxgraph with **angularjs** client-side library dynamically. Didnt find any relevant document which states same. Can someone help me out with this integration like what files need to be integrated and what to call from html file to make functional.

```
app.js var app = angular.module('app', ['mxGraph']);
```

**mxcontroller.js:**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'mxgraph',
 function($scope, mxgraph) {
          $scope.main = function(container)
     {

             var graph = new mxgraph(container);
             var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
             graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
             try
             {
                 var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello,', 20, 20, 80, 30);
                 var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'World!', 200, 150, 80, 30);
             }
            finally
             {
                 graph.getModel().endUpdate();
             }
     }; }]);
```

`index.html` included mxgraph `javascript/src` folders

**mx.html**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as controller" id="content-container">
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're already using an AngularJS factory, service, or provider for mxGraph, you're going to need to use AngularJS dependency injection to use it in your application.

For example, somewhere before your controller:

```
let mxGraph = angular.module('mxGraph', []);
mxGraph.factory("mxgraph", function() {
    return window.mxGraph; 
});
```

You should then be able to inject it into your application like so:

```
app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'mxgraph', function($scope, mxgraph) { ... }]);
```

Comment: I am getting error at mxClient: 

TypeError: element.addEventListener is not a function
    at Object.addListener (mxClient.js:9440)

Comment: I believe that error is separate from the issue described in your question. It sounds like you're trying to attach an event listener to an element that does not exist. For help with that, please open a new question and include the relevant code causing that error.